# Out of the box rollup field NumberOfOpportunities on Campaign is not calculating

Tags: soql, roll-up-summary

So i have two campaigns one in production one in our dev, both have the the same data with minor differences in text fields.

Then i've created opps from the related list page on these campaigns and i've created standalone opps which i then added the campaign to the lookup field (standard field).

When i query production in workbench

SELECT Name, Id, NumberOfOpportunities, (select Id, name from opportunities) FROM Campaign  where Id = 'campaignInProduction'

I'll get three opportunities but the NumberOfOpportunities is equal to 0

now when i query the same thing in dev i get 3 opportunities where the NumberOfOpportunities is equal to 3. There's no differences between the Opportunities in either instance, same with the campaign...yet in production it doesn't calculate but in dev it does.

I've used salesforce inspector to go over all the field data in both objects and they match more or less. I really don't see what can be causing this issue.

edit: tried downloading the campaign object into my IDE to look at this fields XML to see what the parameters are......

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>NumberOfOpportunities</fullName>
</CustomField>
```

....

which tells me nothing on how this field actually works. Also i know it's asynchronous but i doubt asynchronous means 2+ days.

Comment: NumberOfOpportunities is calculated asynchronously: 
 https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219426/campaign-opportunities-in-campaign-field.  If you need a realtime rollup, you'll have to use a tool like Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries.

Comment: @DavidCheng But asynchronous doesn't mean 2+ days does it?

Comment: I recommend opening a case with Salesforce support.